# update to 14.10 from 14.04 without upgrading to 15.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kubuntu

How can I update from 14.04 to 14.10? Update manager and `do-release-upgrade` appear like they will update to 15.04 rather than 14.10.

As an additional question all my settings and icons will stay intact when I upgrade, correct?

Comment: I would either stick with 14.04 or go to 15.04. 14.10 will end in July so it is a mere 3 months of support.

Comment: Ubuntu only allows you to upgrade sequentially either from release to release or from LTS to LTS. So from 14.04 you can either upgrade to 14.10 or 16.04 LTS in April (04) of 2016, when it comes out. There is no way to upgrade directly from 14.04 LTS to 15.04.

Comment: It should upgrade to 14.10 first. Please add the output of `do-release-upgrade -c` to [your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/615556/edit).

Comment: it says: Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '14.10' available. Does this mean do-release-upgrade WILL upgrade to 14.10?